# Представление чисел с плавающей точкой

Tags: информатика

Почему при представлении записи числа с плавающей точкой для записи порядков был выбран код со сдвигом вместо дополнительного кода?

Comment: А разве порядок записывается не в дополнительном коде?

Comment: Причём здесь железо? Вы имеете в виду форматы для обмена такие как IEEE 754 binary64? @Byulent экспонента хранится как беззнаковое число (из которого смещение вычесть надо), чтобы сравнивать числа удобнее было по сравнению с дополнительным кодом (соседние float с одинаковым знаком имеют  битовое представления, которые подряд идут — прибавление бита сдвигает от нуля). В тему: [Comparing Floating Point Numbers (2012)](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/)

Comment: @jfs Да,имею в виду формат записи чисел с плавающей точкой из стандарта IEEE 754.